# How to get the charge ID from Stripe using PHP?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

First of all, I am aware that this question has been asked but they didn't explain how to get the information using

```
 charge.succeeded
```

I am creating an auth and capture charge using Stripe. I need the charge ID to confirm/capture the charge.

The following code creates the charge but doesn't charge until it's been approved.

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $price,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $custID, // obtained with Stripe.js
    "description" => "Charge for test@example.com",         
    "capture" => false
));
```

I assumed that I could get the charge ID by doing:

```
$chargeID = $charge->id;
```

because that's how I get the customer ID when I create a customer. But I get nothing when I echo out the variable, which doesn't help since I want to save it in a database. I've looked everywhere but can't find anything concrete or recent.

Then to complete the charge. I have to capture it this way:

```
$ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve("$chargeID");
$ch->capture();
```

This is all from the Stripe API Reference but it doesn't explain how to get the charge ID. It doesn't even tell you how to get the customer ID, luckily Stack Overflow came through with that one.

This is all done using PHP.

Comment: Are you assigning a variable to `charge::create()` ? What's in it?

Comment: `$charge->id` should work, assuming you're using `$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(...`.

Comment: `$charge->id` works in my application.

Comment: I don't use `capture=>false`, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: Indeed, it does not.

Comment: @rjdown that was my issue!! I kept forgetting $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(... Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Stripe's Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge), when creating a new charge you get `Stripe\Charge JSON` object in return (or an exception if something went wrong).

You can `var_dump` the object you just created to see what your object looks like, but according the the `API` you can use the `id` of the returned object:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $price,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $custID, // obtained with Stripe.js
    "description" => "Charge for test@example.com",         
    "capture" => false
));

// you can use the var_dump function to see what's inside the $charge object
// var_dump($charge);

$chargeID = $charge->id;
```

(And you don't need to call the `Charge::retrieve` again, you can use the current `$charge` object).

Comment: thank you. I can't believe I forgot the assignment. It works now. Thanks everyone who answered.

Comment: @Maria, you are welcome. If the answer is correct you are welcome to accept it or mark it as useful.

Comment: I would but since my reputation is less than 15, it won't do much for the public display.